# How to secure data of clients in my Azure instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, saas

My company developed a business suite which is not a SaaS platform now. We're in beta mode now and will launch V2 within next 2 months. Currently we are creating instance for interested clients (free for a year) but getting questions that their data is secured. Now, my question is, since we are creating their instances on our Azure platform,is there a way to make sure that we won't be able to access their data anyway?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Azure platform cannot ensure that alone. You'll need to architect the system such that you do not have direct access to data (devs not having access to production DB, IP address restrictions etc.). I think this question is a bit too broad, and is more about general software architecture than Azure specifically.

Comment: @juunas Thanks but when you create a customer's instance on Azure and use AzureSQL for customers, is there any option to restrict and share that info/details with the customer (technical knowledgeable customer like CEO of an 200 people-based IT company). Any suggestions in that scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the security setup you can configure and present are -

1. Configure firewall rules to restrict access to db based on the originating IP address of each request. You can share the firewall settings that only specific Virtual Machines/Computers have access to the client's database.
2. Authentication to the database. We can remove any SQL authentication(username/password based) and configure only Azure Integrated security  for the applications accessing the database. Best practice would be using service accounts to access the db. You can showcase this too.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @Avanish